# How to get Multiple Data in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am trying to send multiple datas to a player.

Error: Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column Index out of range, 2 > 1.

Can you help me to fix this problem?

```
public void sendHomeList(Player player){
        String query = "SELECT Homename FROM " + connectionConfig.getHomeTable() + " WHERE OwnerUUID=\"" + player.getUniqueId() + "\"";

        Optional<Connection> optionalConnection = instance.connectionOptional;

        try {
            Statement statement = optionalConnection.get().createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

            int i = 1;
            while(resultSet.next()) {
                player.sendMessage(resultSet.getString(i));
                i++;
            }

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems you have one column for each row and you increment `col + 1` with each iteration

Comment: how do i fix it?

Comment: Use `getString(1)`, not `i`. You always want column 1, and the loop takes care of the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the column index for each row, the call of `resultSet.next()` will check if there are more columns and if yes go inside the loop then fetch the column with the column index number or name of the column

```
while(resultSet.next()) {
    player.sendMessage(resultSet.getString(1));
}
```